# React native uuid [Error: crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported]

Tags: android, ios, react-native, uuid

**In React native project uuid library giving runtime error**

> Error: crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See
> https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported

Answer (score 6):

"getRandomValues() not supported"

> This error occurs in environments
> where the standard crypto.getRandomValues() API is not supported. This
> issue can be resolved by adding an appropriate polyfill:

React Native

```
Install react-native-get-random-values
Import it before uuid:
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

Comment: you could also use https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react-native-uuid